# Four-velocity of hypersurface in relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry

I was thinking about the boundary condition of intersection surface in special relativistic hydrodynamics, I tried to Establish boundary conditions on the moving interface,and then return to the laboratory reference system .

in newtonian hydrodynamics , if the surface is$F\left(\vec{r},t\right)=0$,then derive it with respect to t,  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\nabla\ F\cdot\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=0$,Notice that the normal vector of the surface is $\vec{n}=\frac{\nabla F}{\left|\nabla F\right|}$,we can rewrite the equation :$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+(\vec{n}\cdot\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt})\left|\nabla F\right|=0$ ,then the normal velocity of the surface is $D_n=\vec{n}\cdot\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\left|\nabla F\right|}$.

Now in relativity , if a hypersurace is described as $F=const$,then its normal covector is $dF$ or $\nabla_aF$ using abstract index notation invented by Penrose. So how to define the four velocity of the hypersurface independt of an observer? I have an idea that the four velocity of the hypersurface should be defined as follows ,if there's an instantaneous observer  ,then the projection of four velocity and the normal vector of the hypersuface on the surface of  simultaneity of the observer should share the same direction.